# Azure DevOps Pipeline - React Js application build was failing during build (npm run build)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I was using vmImage: ubuntu-latest. Getting many errors during build (npm run build) such as:

ERROR in ./src/components/*********/testCard.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './green.png' in '/home/vsts/work/1/s/web/src/components/testCard'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All these run errors during build due to **referred components are case sensitive** when we use vmImage: ubuntu-latest.

To avoid those build errors, use vmImage: macOS-10.15 or latest macOs.

Comment: Case sensitive was exactly the problem, and I couldn't get it locally because I was running on a Windows machine.